# How do I configure Grub to boot a 2nd Linux OS on a 2nd hard drive in PC Environment

Tags: dual-boot

I'm a novice at best, but I've been trying to figure out how to dual boot 2 linux systems from separate hard drives in a PC/tower environment.  I've searched youtube, google, and even here and I've posted questions in different forums.  I don't know much about configuring Grub, so please be detailed because some of the answers I've gotten in the past have been vague at best. 
I have Ubuntu 14.04 server on 1st hard drive, and CentOS 6.7 on 2nd drive, and
I can boot into each system separately but I have reboot the PC and then go to BIOS and I can click on the Hard Disk to boot into CentOS. However, I would like to add the path to load CentOS into the Ubuntu GRUB on the 1st Hard Disk so that I can choose either OS mainly when I want to boot to the CentOS 6.7
on the second Hard Disk.

Please make explanation simple and detailed.  As previous posters seem assume they are talking to an expert. They also believe everyone uses a Laptop, but this is my server. I do know a few things but Grub MBR area is my down fall; but trying to learn.

Comment: Maybe I should have added this :  I want to know how to add the path and/or point Ubuntu Grub to the "CentOS 6.7 (2nd Drive)".  This never worked before, and I have an actual boot-repair disk downloaded and burnt to a DVD.  Instructions do no tell you how to do this particular task.  I've heard it can be done, but I've yet to get any accurate instructions.   I tried using the boot repair disk but it didn't give any logical choices even in advanced mode ??

Answer (score 0):

You are able to login to Ubuntu Server as well as Cent OS. So here are some of the steps:
Login into Ubuntu Server and then configure grub/[boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). You need to start the terminal(Ctrl+Alt+T)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Essentially this will fix your problem. If not please share the pastebin contents. 
Make sure in your Desktop BIOS your first device to boot is your first hard drive which contains Ubuntu Server.

You might need to refer to [boot-info](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) also to debug this issue if needed.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-info && boot-info
```

Comment: I want to know how to add the path and/or point Ubuntu Grub to the "CentOS 6.7 (2nd Drive)".  Are you saying that boot-repair will do this automatically ???  I tried it once before, and boot-info doesn't even mention being able to add another system, especially on a separate drive, to the Grub it just talks about repairing after something gets horked..

Comment: boot-repair should fix this issue.